# How can I drag a polygon based on a mouse-moved event?

Tags: java, input

I have drawn a polygon in Java using `java.awt.Polygon`. I want to move that polygon with the mouse (by dragging it). I know that I have to use `mouseDragged`  method in `addMouseMotionListener`. That way I can know coordinates of the path in along which the mouse is dragging the polygon.

But the problem is that I do not know what to do with the coordinates I get from the mouse to move the polygon. This is a part of the code:

```
public void mouseListeners(DrawEverything det) {
    det.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

            if( isMouseInMe(evt.getX(), evt.getY())){//this "if" checks if the cursor is in the shape when we drag it

                int xTmep , yTemp ;
                xTmep = (int) (evt.getX() - xMousePressed) ;//xMousePressed--> the x position of the mouse when pressed on the shape
                yTemp = (int) (evt.getY() - yMousePressed) ; 

                for(int i = 0 ; i < nPoints ; ++i){
                    xPoints[i]  +=    xTmep;//array of x-positions of the points of polygon
                    yPoints[i]  +=   yTemp;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This part is the main part that I am having trouble with:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < nPoints ; ++i){
    xPoints[i] += xTmep;
    yPoints[i] += yTemp;
}
```

Comment: Get the mouse position when the drag is started and the mouse position at the current time. The change in position is what you're after. You can then scale that appropriately and move the points of your polygon accordingly. Don't add to the coordinates directly. You want to keep a copy of the original position, so while the drag is happening, keep a temporary copy of the polygon vertices.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method to drag objects based on mouse interaction requires the following:

- The ability to detect and respond to mouse down, mouse motion ("moved") and mouse up events.
- The ability to detect if a specific point is "within" the shape you want to drag in some capacity.
- Optionally (depending on your APIs) place to store state about whether or not the drag is in progress and what the original click location of the drag was.

The process, in pseudocode, is as follows:

When you get a mouse-down event, record the drag origin position as the point the user clicked, figure out which shape the mouse hit, and store that shape.

```
void OnMouseDown (int mouseX, int mouseY) {
  m_previousPosition = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);

  foreach (var polygon in the scene) {
    if (polygon.containsPoint(m_dragOrigin)) {
      m_dragTarget = polygon;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The above method is simplistic, but illustrative. It simply tests every polygon in the scene to see if the clicked point (now stored in `m_previousPosition`) is within it, and if so, makes that polygon the "drag target," the object being moved. It stops after the first one is found. A complex scene may need a better method of doing the picking, for efficiency, but this should get you started.

Now every time you get a mouse-moved event, check if you are dragging something (if you have a non-null drag target). If you are, compute the *delta* between the mouse's current position and the previous position. That gives you the amount you need to move the drag target this frame, so move the object accordingly, and set the "previous" position to the current position so that the next mouse move event will perform the same basic logic:

```
void OnMouseMoved (int mouseX, int mouseY) {
  if (m_dragTarget != null) {
    m_dragTarget.X += mouseX - m_previousPosition.X;
    m_dragTarget.Y += mouseY - m_previousPosition.Y;

    m_previousPosition = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
  }
}
```

Finally, when you get a mouse-up, terminate the drag by clearing the drag target:

```
void OnMouseUp (int mouseX, int mouseY) {
  m_dragTarget = null;
}
```

Note that some APIs provide deltas directly to their mouse-move APIs, so you may be able to use those metrics instead, which can simplify your logic.

It's also useful in practice to store a copy of the original position of the drag shape; for example if you want to easily support cancellation of the drag, or show a "shadow" as the user drags the object, leaving the original untouched until the drag completes, or to avoid floating-point error accumulation in some cases. You may want to consider augmenting the above bare-bones approach accordingly.

In that case you can actually do away with the per-frame delta computation and store the original drag origin point once (not updating it in the move handler), and instead compute the total delta from the original origin to the current point during the move handler and use that as the translation value for the ghosted drag shape.

Comment: I would avoid to track previous position if you are not interested into computing an approximation of "how much pixel you have traveled so far". I would instead record the mouse position when down and nulling when up, then computing a displacement vector between current mouse position and the position the mouse was when down.

Comment: Yeah, that what I was trying to get at in my last paragraph or so.

Comment: oh, you are right, I missed that; Anyway I dont understand why update position then delta vs update delta from starting position